# UI doesn't update when you pick a new badge

Tags: bug, status-deferred, profile-page, badges, badge-progress

(I am reusing a screenshot from another thread as mine is gone now.)

I just got the enthusiast badge and then when I picked my next one by clicking the "track the next one", this UI doesn't update:

[image: Image of new badge alert]

You just get dropped back from the modal to this same prompt to pick the next one.

I did it twice to be sure and then just refreshed the page instead and now the UI has gone back to normal:

[image]

I am using version Chrome 75.0.3770.142 (official build) (64-bit) on Windows 10.

Comment: Long standing issue (MSE): [“Track the next one” doesn’t update the page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304836/339911)

Comment: Version version 75.0.3770.142 of what? [Google Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome)?

Comment: yes chrome, didnt notice I missed it -- updated now