# Only tag-related badges appeared available for tracking after a badge was earned

Tags: bug, profile-page, badges, tag-badges, badge-progress

I was awarded the [Inquisitive](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4128/inquisitive) badge (30 well-received questions) on Stack Overflow (which was a tracked badge). The badges section on the profile page showed the options to "Choose a new badge" to track or "Let us pick".

If I clicked on the "Choose a new badge" option, the popup with badge selection appeared, but it contained only bronze badges; all of the badges seemed to be tag-related ones only (so, e.g., 30/100 points for [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag). I don't have any silver tag-related badges being earned, so probably that was the reason no higher than bronze appeared. The badges that normally appear as options when clicking the "Next badge" cog were absent. I wanted to track the [Socratic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4129/socratic) badge, but it was not there.

Therefore I clicked "Let us pick" and... the Socratic badge was chosen automatically. Now the usual "Next badge" cog is back and if I click it, the standard badges selection appears, which does NOT include the tag-related badges.

It seems that the set of badges to be chosen with the "Next badge" cog and the "Choose" button after a badge was earned is different and mutually exclusive.

Comment: Unfortunatelly not, at that moment I thought that maybe site logic has changed and did not consider it a bug. And after I clicked `Let us pick` the badge section changed to the usual one and I am not able to click the `Choose` option again.

Comment: This is the subject of this bug. The `Cog` on usual view and `Choose` on the view after badge award displayed completely different selection of badges. Unless you want to see that I don't have any tag-related badges to select in the `Cog` selection.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is two different places where you can track a badge, meaning you can track two different badges. One is in the "Reputation" box, the other is in the "Badges" box. See below for an example.

[image: Example of profile area]

One allows the selection of tag badges, the other allows the selection of non-tag badges.

Comment: Sorry, but you misunderstood my submission, but also gave us additional hint. When you are awarded a badge that you have been tracking, the contents of the `BADGES` component is replaced with a completely different one. There's a message `You have earned badge X` and 2 buttons `Choose new to track` and `Let us pick` (or something like this). If you click `Choose` it displays the popup for `Choose which tag badge to track` from `REPUTATION` component (which you are referring to) instead of  `Choose which badge to track` cog from `BADGES` component.

Comment: The new contents of the `BADGES` component looks like a newer version of this: [UI doesn't update when you pick a new badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387320/ui-doesnt-update-when-you-pick-a-new-badge).

Comment: Effectively, the notification opened the wrong dialog?

Comment: Yes, the button for "Choosing the next badge to track" opened the tag-badge popup instead of badge pop-up.